# Making list of functions in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I want to create a list of functions in Scheme. As I figured out it would be something like this

```
(define (sqr x) (* x x))
(define (dbl x) (* 2 x))
(define (add-5 x) (+ 5 x))

(define list-of-funs '(sqr dbl add-5))
```

but I wonder how I can call separate functions from the list. Is there a better way to define a list of functions and call them separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. You should use `list`, rather than quoting:

```
(define list-of-funs (list sqr dbl add-5))
```

The reason for this is that `'(sqr dbl add-5)` produces a list of *symbols*, whereas `(list sqr dbl add-5)` produces a list of procedure objects. You can invoke procedure objects. You cannot invoke symbols.

You can access the functions individually, by using `first`, `second`, or `third` (from SRFI 1) to pick elements out of the list, e.g.,

```
((first list-of-funs) 49)    ; => 7
```

Or else you might decide you want to `map` through them, or whatever. e.g.,

```
(define (square-double-and-add5 x)
  (map (lambda (f) (f x)) list-of-funs))
```